# C++ Program stuck in a loop

Tags: c++, function, loops, rpn

So this program is supposed to take a string and convert it to Reverse Polish Notation, and then generate the assembly code for it.

For example.  If I was to input "x = y", the program would return

"RPN :  xy="

"Code:
1 lod y
2 sto x"

However the program instead returns gibberish and continues to do so until it runs out of memory.

Here's the input function

```
void 
getstring()
{
    if(datafile) {
        file.getline(str,241);
        }else{
            cout << "Enter a string, please \n\n";
            cin.getline( str, 241);
            }
            nstring++;
}
```

And these are the functions that work with it.

```
void 
internalize()
{
    int i, j;
    static char inter[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 6, 4, 0, 5, 0, 7,
                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,
                           0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
                           23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                           0,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,
                           49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        char ch, code, k, *p, *q;
        cout << "internal form: \n\n";
        k=0;
        q=inform;
        for(p=str;*p;p++){
            *q++ = code = inter[(int)*p];
                if(k+code == 0){
                    k = p-str+1;
                    ch = *p;
                    }
            }
        *q = 0;
        for(i=j=0, p = inform;p++,j++;j<len){
        cout << setw(3) << (int)*p;

            if(++i == 16){
                cout << '\n';
                i = 0;
                }
        }   
        if (i !=0){
        cout <<'\n';
        }
        if((err = (0<k))!=0){
        cout << '\n**' << (int)k << "-th nonblank char <" <<ch<<"> is illegal. **\n";
        }
}

void
makerpn()
{
    static char pr[]={0,0,1,2,3,3,4,4};

    char n, *p, *r, s, *t;
    cout << "\nRPN:\n\n";
    t = stak - 1;
    r = rpn;

    for (p = inform;p++ ; *p){
        if(7 < (s = *p)){
        *r++ = s;
        //a
        }else if(s == 1){
            *++t = s;
        } else{
            while(1){
                if(t<stak){
                    *++t = s;
                    break;
                } else if(pr[s] <= pr[n = *t--]){
                *r++ = n;
                } else if(3 < n+s){
                    *++t = n;
                    *++t = s;
                }
            break;  
            }
    }   
        while(stak <= t){
        *r++ = *t--;
        }
        *r = '\0';
        for(r=rpn;*r;r++){
            cout << ext[(int)*r];
        }
        cout << "\n\n";     
}}

void
gencode()
{
        void emit(char, char);
        char a,j,lop,n1,n2,*p,*t;       
        cout << "Generated symbolic code \n\n";
        j = len = lop = 0;
        t = p = rpn;

            while(3 <(a = *++p)){           
                if(7 <a){
                    *++t = a;
                        if((++lop == 2) && (0<len)){
                        n2=*t--;

                        n1=*t--;
                        *++t=j+60;
                        *++t=n1;
                        *++t=n2;
                        emit(2,(j++)+60);
                        }
                }else {
                    if(lop == 1){
                    emit(a,*t--);
                        }else{ 
                            if( 1 < lop){
                            n2 = *t--;
                            n1 = *t--;
                            emit(1,n1);
                            emit(a,n2);
                            }else {
                                if((a==4) || (a==6)){
                                    n1 = *t--;
                                    emit(a,n1);
                            }else {      
                                n1=*t--;
                                emit(2,j+60);
                                emit(1,n1);
                                emit(a,j+60);
                                if( 59 < n1){
                                    --j;}}}}}}  
                        lop = 0;
}
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the loops but I'm not sure what.  I've been tweaking them for a while and all I managed to do was to get it to repeat Hp?  instead of HW over and over.

Comment: TL;DR! Please try to narrow it down to the relevant code you have a problem with, or create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also, please try to come up with some good and descriptive variable names. For example, what is `a`? What's it supposed to represent? What's the purpose of the variable?

Comment: In makerpn() you have: for (p = inform;p++ ; *p)

Comment: There's a fine line between terse and obscure, and you're about a mile past it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for (p = inform;p++ ; *p)` will continue until the next value of `p` is `nullptr`, and each round will dereference `p` and discard the result - you probably meant this the other way around.

Similar is this case: `for(i=j=0, p = inform;p++,j++;j<len)` which will continue running until `j++` becomes `0` and discard the result of the comparision `j<len` each iteration.

In general, there is really only one problem here: Your code is really, really hard to read. Try to break it down into manageable chunks, and verify each one is doing what you want. That way, if there remains a single chunk not doing what you want, you can identify it, and ask for that one specifically instead of dumping a whole program.